# conditional summation in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(Claim2015 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Claim2016 = c(1, 0, 1,
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), Claim2017 = c(0,
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), Claim2018 = c(0,
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), Claim2019 = c(0,
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA,
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to create a conditional summation, that says out of those who had a claim in 2015, how many had in 2016; out of those with both, how many had in 2017 and so on (the sum will decrease).

So the output expected is:

```
 db <- data_frame(Had2015 = 20, Had2016 = 15, Had2017 = 9, Had2018 = 7, Had2019 = 5)
```

What I have started doing is

```
df1 <- df %>% group_by_all %>% count
```

And this organizes the output in a way that makes it easier to count - so I am summing the `n` for those with 1, those with 1 & 1, those with 1 & 1 & 1 and so on - just don't know how to do this automatically.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using base R, we can incrementally loop over each column and count number of rows with all 1.

```
sapply(seq_along(df), function(x) sum(rowSums(df[1:x] == 1) == x))
#[1] 20 15  9  7  5
```

Answer (score 4):

Another similar idea in base R, which exposes the `accumulate` argument of `Reduce` can be,

```
sapply(Reduce(`data.frame`, split.default(df, seq_along(df)), accumulate = TRUE), function(i)
                                                                  sum(rowSums(i) == ncol(i)))

#[1] 20 15  9  7  5
```

Comment: `Reduce` crossed my mind too, when reading the Q. Unless I'm missing something, a more efficient (less copying, less computations) use of `Reduce`  would be to make all computations while (and not after) subsetting the "data.frame"; i.e. `Reduce("&", df[, -1], accumulate = TRUE, init = as.logical(df[[1]]))` (and then `sum` each element).